# Reloading Radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]How to reload radio button list value?
I assignedtext box value as follows,

```
document.getElementById('txtvalue' + id).value = document.getElementById('txtoriginalvalue' + id + '2').innerHTML;
```

I tried same for radio button but i can't able to reload. please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: can you explain a bit more on 'reload radio button'? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: while editing,   radio button value is not getting set.

Comment: which radio button you want to set.can you share the DOM.

Comment: I have save and edit operation for rows in a table. i saved a row includes radio button.once i saved, i edited radio button value to female,previously it was male. then i didnt save i cancelled operation. next time i pressed edit, it has to show male. but its showing female which i chose and cancelled operation...please help me out

Comment: document.getElementById('radiooriginalvalue' + id + '2').innerHTML;   I have saved previous value(original) in this . how to assign it to  radio button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

radioButtonVal= document.getElementById('radiooriginalvalue' + id + '2').innerHTML;

$("input[name=radiobuttonname'" + id + "'][value=" + radioButtonVal + "]").attr('checked', 'checked');

By doing this I got output .

Answer (score 1):

Check out the link below.

http://jsbin.com/nohoqomuru/1/edit?html,js,output

```
function Cancel(){
        var sId = '#'+selectedId;
        $(sId).prop("checked", true);

        $('#Save').attr('disabled' , true);
      $('#Cancel').attr('disabled' , true);
}
```

Comment: If I will checked for eg:- value 1 and saved . later i edited with value 2 and cancelled the operation,again i clicked edit, then it has to by default show value 1. but if i do like this it will show value 2.

Comment: is it something like you are trying to set default value, when ever the page loads ?

Comment: No. i saved value 1 ,i edited value 1 to value 2, then  cancelled the operation ,next time while editing, value 1 should populate on radio button.

Comment: getting "Cannot read property 'id' of null" and getting null value for "sId" and "selectedId". I have created every controls in javascript